# glMultiDrawElements and glDrawElements equivalences

Tags: opengl

I have read on many sites that `glMultiDrawElements` is "equivalent" to doing this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < drawCount; ++i){
    glDrawElements(mode, counts[i], type, indices[i]);
}
```

But it is that part of "equivalents" that I do not understand. How equivalent? If both are exactly the same, what is the point of the `glMultiDrawElements` function if I can do the same with `glDrawElements` function and a for loop?

Does the `glMultiDrawElements` function give me some performance advantage?

Comment: A single GL driver round-trip vs. N round-trips.

Comment: I want to think then that it is a HUGE advantage to use several drawing calls in one, right?

Answer (score 4):

`glMultiDrawElements` *behaves* as if you did those draw calls. Performance is not, and never has been, part of "behavior". The OpenGL specification defines behavior; it does not and cannot specify performance.

It should also be noted that, as of OpenGL 4.6/[ARB_shader_draw_parameters](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_shader_draw_parameters.txt), these are no longer *exactly* equivalent functions. Multi-draw functions have the ability to set [the `gl_DrawID` input parameter to a Vertex Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Shader#Other_inputs), thus allowing the shader pipeline to know which draw operation in the middle of a multi-draw operation is being executed.

You can't get that with `glDrawElements`.

Comment: Well but then, is it better to use the glMultiDrawElements function than the glDrawElements function?

This because as I understand calls to drawing are minimized, right?

Comment: @JavierRamírez: If you want to compute `(A*B) + C`, and you have a function to add numbers, a function to multiply numbers, and a function that multiplies two numbers and add them to a third all in one call, which do you pick? All things being equal, you always pick the most specific and/or least flexible function. It will be no worse than the less specific one, and it could potentially be better. So it's no-contest if both are available and applicable.